# What image does apple use for app store if an iTunes Artwork image is not specified?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, app-store, itunes

My app's icon has a circular logo with a blue background. I included all the required icon sizes for retina, iPad etc. but I read several places that the iTunes Artwork image is "optional but recommended" so I did not include it, thinking it would look fine if any of the others were scaled up a little bit for the devices app store. But, now that it's accepted, when I go into the app store, on the device or iTunes, it looks like they took one of the icons, made a really bad cut out of the circular part to get rid of the backround (there are chunks of white pixels sticking off of the top of it now), then put it over a black background... Why would this be the result?? The icon looks very nice on all the different devices' home screens...

Comment: Closed? does this not "relate to software development in some way"? This is about which images in the plist of my program are used where. It's like asking which piece of code affects which part of an the app... No need for a downvote at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's optional but recommended because the generated image is going to be undefined in its quality and contents. In your case, they made a bad cut. Take 10 minutes and make a good 512px by 512px image (even if it's just scaled up from your icon) and upload it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I just read this on Apple's Technical Q&A page: "Note: If you don't provide one of the listed optional icons, the system will automatically scale one of your existing icons to an appropriate size. However, it is strongly recommended that your application supply all the icons listed with specific sizes needed." So did someone physically cut it out to put it on a different background? Why would they do that and not just scale it up?

Comment: They likely have an automated process that tries to intelligently make the icon, and in some cases it doesn't work very well.

Comment: They might not bother being smart about it - you've been warned about it and it's in their benefit to make you do it properly so why spend their time and effort making it nice?

Answer (score -1):

You add the iTunes Artwork file manually when you add the app to the store...right before you upload screens for the app.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the OP's question. Should be a comment instead

Answer (score -1):

I just always make a 512x512 version of my icon and upload it to the AppStore -- that's probably why they recommend it!

Comment: This isn't an answer to the OP's question. Should be a comment instead

Comment: Good point, I'm still figuring my way around this system.